# Problem with the Routing Path Express, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I have a question about deleting data in the database using Express and NodeJS as I have a form that is deleted.pug to get the ID input from the user then used that ID to find the record in the database to delete that.

I don't know why when I clicked on the "Delete Record" button in the index.pug, I get the error "Cannot GET /delete/". Therefore, I couldn't load the form for the user to input the id.

However, in the address bar, when I typed http://localhost:3000/api/delete/5, then the city with the id is 5 was deleted in the database. Can someone help me so that I can load the delete form to get the input from the user instead of letting them directly put the id in the URL? Thank you, and I appreciate it

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('../config/db.config');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'DELETE FROM tblCitiesImport WHERE id=?';
    mysql.query(sql, req.params.id, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('../views/deletesuccess');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

delete.pug

```
html
    head
    body
        form(action='/api/delete', method='POST')
            p
                | ID:
                input(name='ID', value='', type='text')
            input(value='Submit', type='submit')
```

index.pug

```
extends layout

block layout-content
    div.View.WelcomeView
        h1.Banner City Database Site
        div.Message
            div.Title
                h3 IS219 Final
                h1 Cities Project
            span.Details Access the Cities Records Web Portal
        div.NavButtons
            if isAuthenticated
                a(href="http://localhost:8000")
                    div.NavButton View Records
                a(href="/user")
                    div.NavButton My Profile
                a(href="/delete/")
                    div.NavButton Delete Record
                a(href="/logout")
                    div.NavButton Logout
            else
                a(href="/login")
                    div.NavButton Log in
```

db structure

```
CREATE DATABASE citiesData;
use citiesData;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblCitiesImport (
    `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fldName` VARCHAR(21) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `fldLat` NUMERIC(6, 4),
    `fldLong` NUMERIC(7, 4),
    `fldCountry` VARCHAR(19) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `fldAbbreviation` VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `fldCapitalStatus` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `fldPopulation` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const expressSession = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
require('dotenv').config();

const open = require('open');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const jwtAuthz = require('express-jwt-authz');
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
const dbConn = require('./config/db.config');
const authRouter = require('./auth');
const citiesRoutes = require('./routes/cities.routes');

// App Variables
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';

// Session Configuration
const session = {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
};

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    // Serve secure cookies, requires HTTPS
    session.cookie.secure = true;
}

// Passport Configuration
const strategy = new Auth0Strategy(
    {
        domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
        // Access tokens are used to authorize users to an API
        // accessToken is the token to call the Auth0 API or a secured 3rd-party API
        // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token (JWT)
        // profile has all the information from the user
        return done(null, profile);
    },
);

// App Configuration
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(expressSession(session));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

passport.use(strategy);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

// Creating custom middleware with Express
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});

// Authorization middleware. When used, the
// Access Token must exist and be verified against
// the Auth0 JSON Web Key Set
const checkJwt = jwt({
    // Dynamically provide a signing key
    // based on the kid in the header and
    // the signing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: 'https://YOURSDOMAIN.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
    }),

    // Validate the audience and the issuer.
    audience: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cities',
    issuer: ['https://YOURSDOMAIN.us.auth0.com/'],
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
});

// Router Mounting
app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// Routes Definitions
const secured = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        return next();
    }
    req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
    res.redirect('/login');
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
});

app.get('/user', secured, (req, res, next) => {
    const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = req.user;
    res.render('user', {
        title: 'Profile',
        userProfile: userProfile,
    });
});

// This route is not needed authentication
app.get('/api/public', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'You are in the public endpoint! Authentication is not needed to see this.',
    });
});

// This route is needed authentication
app.get('/api/private', checkJwt, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'You are in the private endpoint! Authentication is needed to see this.',
    });
});

// using as middleware
app.use('/api/v1/cities', citiesRoutes);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Your delete endpoint /api/delete/:id but you send /delete request. You need to add ID parameter like /api/delete/xyz in the index.pug file.

Comment: Can you show me how to get the id from the delete form and put it in the /api/delete/id in the index.pug?

Comment: also it should be `router.post`

Comment: I did fix the /api/delete/id in the index.pug. However, no form is displayed when I clicked on the "Delete Record" button, but instead, it directly deletes the city which has the id in the URL. For instance such as /api/delete/10 then the city has the id 10 will be deleted without displaying the form for the user to input the id.